# I can't put post values from forms in variables?

Tags: php, variables, http-post

In the code below the variables I create ($host, $username etc.) remain empty. What am I doing wrong? When I just make a variable with a regular string it works fine.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="host" id="host-input" value="" />
<input type="text" name="dbname" id="db-input" value="" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="password-input" value="" />
<input type="text" name="username" id="username-input" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $host = $POST['host'];
        $username = $POST['username'];
        $dbname = $POST['dbname'];
        $password = $POST['password'];

        $file = 'testbestandje.php';
        // Open the file to get existing content
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        // Append a new person to the file
        $current .= '<? $conn=mysql_connect("'.$host.'","'.$dbname.'","'.$password.'") or die("Kan geen verbinding maken met de DB server"); 
 mysql_select_db("'.$username.'",$conn) or die("Kan database niet selecteren"); ?>'; 
        // Write the contents back to the file
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Comment: `$host = $POST['host'];` should be `$host = $_POST['host'];` - you're missing the underscores.

Comment: what a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST` is the correct variable name

```
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)